# If a dice is rolled twenty times, what are the odds that a 3 and a 4 occur successively at least once?

Tags: probability, dice, computational-mathematics

So at first this seemed like a fairly simple binomial trial problem, but I realized you can't model this as 19 separate events because each event sort of interferes with the next, in that, for

3 1 2 4

The one precludes the next "set of two" from being possible. So I'm not sure how to tackle this. I wrote some Python code to experimentally find a number that's close enough:

https://gist.github.com/danishanish/0c52d4585ef7bd0508644311990e20b5

So I've run this a whole bunch of times and the answer looks a lot like it's around ~0.155438 from a few thousand trials. I have two questions:

1. What is the proper mathematic way of computing this solution?
2. Is there any problem in my code that would keep it from finding the solution when scaled?

Comment: Have you learned about Markov chains?

Comment: Is the question the same as "probability of the string `34` appearing in strings of $20$ digit numbers consisting only of digits $1$ through $6$"?

Comment: @saulspatz No, would that be relevant?

Comment: @AndrewChin Yes, I believe it would be

Comment: Yes, Markov chains would be an obvious way to solve the problem.

Comment: As for the program, it is correct.

Comment: A $3$ and a $4$ successively **and in that order**?  Or does the string $43$ also count as "good"?

Comment: @saulspatz unfortunately, not familiar with those

Comment: @RobertShore And in that order.

Comment: Well, you can follow up @AndrewChin's comment and try it with the principle of inclusion and exclusion.  There are $6^{20}$ possible strings.  How many ways have a $3$-$4$?  Think of this as a digraph, so we have $19$ characters in all, so there are $19\cdot6^{18}$ possibilities.  Now we have to worry about the strings with two $3$-$4$'s, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean a $3$ and a $4$ consecutively and in that order, you can approach the problem using combinatorial methods using the principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Treat the $34$ string as a single unit, which can appear in any of $19$ different locations.    The remaining $18$ digits can have any of $6$ different values, so that gives you a total of $19 \cdot 6^{18}$ possible combinations.

But that is an overcount because arrangements with a pair of $34$ combinations are counted at least twice.  So you need to subtract off all sequences with a pair of $34$ combinations. There are $\binom {18}{2}$ possible positions the $16$ singlets and $2$ pairs can take.

Now you need to add back all arrangements with $3$ $34$ combinations.  There are $\binom{17}{3}$ possible positions the $14$ singlets and $3$ pairs can take.  Then subtract all sequences with $4$ of the pairs, etc., until finally you subtract the single arrangement with $10$ of the combinations.  It's a little tedious but manageable.

Finally, divide by $6^{20}$, which is the total number of combinations.  Thus,

$$ \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^{10} (-1)^{k+1} \binom{20-k}{k}6^{20-2k}}{6^{20}}.$$

Comment: Dropped it into my calculator and I get a negative number - something seems wrong, but I've double checked the input. It comes out to -0.66, which is probably not right. What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know.  The sum should start with (positive) $\binom{19}{1} \cdot 6^{18}$ and end by subtracting $1$.

Comment: I got $0.4232617074516266$ for the fraction

Comment: @RobertShore I must've just messed something up. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @danishanish Glad I could help.  Upvotes are always appreciated in addition to acceptances for answers you find useful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need inclusion-exclusion. If $a_n$ is the number of acceptable sequences of $n$ rolls, then $a_n=6a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$ with initial conditions $a_1=6$, $a_2=35$, and now apply standard techniques for solving constant coefficient homogeneous linear recurrences. Or just write a program to compute $a_{20}$ from the initial values and the recurrence.

Comment: I don't see how you get your recurrence relation, nor do I see how you get your initial conditions.

Comment: @Robert, I should have said that I'm counting sequences in which we *don't* get a three followed immediately by a four – it will be necessary to subtract my numbers from the total number of outcomes of $n$ rolls. Given that, as to the initial conditions: how many acceptable outcomes are there when you roll a die once? How many are there when you roll a die twice, seeing as how the only unacceptable outcome is when the first roll is a three and then the second roll is a four? continued next comment.

Comment: As for the recurrence, there are $6a_{n-1}$ outcomes for $n$ rolls where the first $n-1$ rolls are acceptable; of these, the unacceptable sequences are the $a_{n-2}$ acceptable sequences of $n-2$ rolls that are followed by a three and then a four.

Comment: I see it now.  I think it would be very helpful to incorporate this information into the answer.

Comment: @Robert, I might do that – tomorrow (getting close to bedtime here).